# check line with custom value in c#

Tags: c#, line

guys i use this simple code to read the mp-config.cfg file and but just read.
how i can check this line:

```
r_full "value"
```

and if the value of this line is "0" retutn this error:

```
"Sorry but have to use full Screen mod."
```

Then force write the value to "1"

my code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace checkFull
{
    class TextFileReader
    {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Textreader tr = new StreamReader(@"player\mp-config.cfg");

        how do that?

        // close the stream
        tr.Close();
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: So you assume we all know what `mp-config.cfg` is. But maybe we can help if you post sample input and expected output.

Comment: the file mp-config.cfg have multi-line (text format) and the one of line is r_full "1/0" i need check if this value is 1 or 0

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] parts = File.ReadLines(@"player\mp-config.cfg")
                    .Select(line => line.Split())
                    .Where(x => x.Length > 1)
                    .FirstOrDefault(x => x[0] == "r_full");

string result="";
if (parts != null)
{
   result = parts[1];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    class TextFileReader
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string path = @"player\mp-config.cfg";
            string readText = File.ReadAllText(path);

            string secondWord = readText.Split()[1];
            int value = Int32.Parse(secondWord);

            if (value == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Sorry but have to use full Screen mod.");
                using (StreamWriter outfile = new StreamWriter(path))
                {
                    outfile.Write("r_val 1");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks but the mp-config.cfg is muli-line file and i need check just the line "r_full" and update the value of this line (if is "0" change to "1")

Comment: `secondWord` is really the second word of the file. No matter how many lines there are.